# Excel VBA GetOpenFileName erro com MultiSelect:=True

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um código onde o usuário aperta no botão, abre a a janelinha do explorer com o `GetOpenFilename`, do tipo .txt e ao usuário selecionar o documento ele abrir em uma nova planilha. Porém quero adicionar a opção `MultiSelect` para que ao invés do usuário ter que apertar diversas vezes no botão para abrir vários documentos .txt, ele selecionar os documentos que tem na pasta, exemplo: "10" blocos de notas, e abrir todos.

Segue código abaixo, tudo está dando certo conforme dito acima. Porém ao implementar o Multiselect da ERRO

```
Sub lerTxt()

Dim arquivo As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet


Set Objeto = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 'Criando objeto

arquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt", Title:="Selecione um arquivo", MultiSelect:=True) 'Para abrir o documento, janelinha do explorer

If arquivo = "" Or arquivo = "Falso" Then 'Se arquivo for igual a vazio, ou se ele clicar em cancelar retornar "falso", usuário não selecionou nenhum documento
Exit Sub
End If



Open arquivo For Input As #1

Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)) 'Referencia o objeto para que seja ativada a opção de abrir uma nova planilha

lin = 1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, valorLin
    Cells(lin, 1).Value = valorLin
    lin = lin + 1
Loop

Close #1

Range("A1:A" & lin - 1).TextToColumns Other:=True 'Intervalo em que é inserido os dados e separando por colunas para o tipo de dado escolhido
Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Faz o ajuste de colunas para obter a melhor largura
 

   

End Sub
```

OBS ERROR: Erro em tempo de execução '13': Tipos incompatíveis. Quando seleciono qualquer documento .txt da pasta

Comment: Faltou explicar em qual linha dá o erro, meu caro.

Comment: Mas, se você estiver usando multiselect, seu código deveria dar erro na linha ```Open arquivo For Input As #1```. Isso porque o Open vai exigir uma string com o nome de arquivo, e sua variável ```arquivo```, caso seja feito um multiselect, conterá uma array de strings com os nomes de cada arquivo selecionado (ou seja, os tipos são, deveras, incompatíveis). Portanto, antes do Open, você deveria verificar se é uma array e, nesse caso, iterar a array fazendo um Open para cada item. Deu pra entender a ideia?

Comment: Confesso que não entendi muito bem, tentei alterar o código em base do entendimento que tive da sua explicação. Mas não funcionou

Comment: Como acha que deveria ser feito?

Comment: Diga em que linha dá o erro, só pra confirmar se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Quando executo o código, quando rodo a macro ele abre o GetOpenFile normalmente, abre a pasta consigo selecionar os arquivos que eu quero (mais de um txt) porém quando clico em "abrir", da o seguinte erro: Erro em tempo de execução '13': Tipos incompatíveis, e quando vou depurar o código mostra exatamente na linha do arquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename...Restante da linha

Comment: Eu não posso responder agora porque estou em viagem, mas se ninguém responder eu confiro depois de amanhã.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pela força!

Comment: PORÉM, o erro nessa linha é por causa do tipo de variável. O ```Application.GetOpenFilename``` pode retornar boolean (se fechar sem selecionar), string (se selecionar um arquivo só) ou array de strings (se selecionar vários arquivos). Atribuir este retorno à variável ```arquivo```, que é só tipo string, só funcionará caso você selecione um arquivo só, mas dará o Type Mismatch nas outras duas hipóteses. Para resolver isso, você precisa declarar ```arquivo``` como ```variant```, e não como string.

Comment: Portanto, a primeira correção é mudar aquele começo para ```Dim arquivo as Variant``` (é um passo necessário, mas ainda vai dar erro mais pra frente, porque teremos que testar o que está dentro da variável arquivo, que o ```GetOpenFilename``` retornou). Essa é a parte que eu só posso ajudar quando voltar de viagem.

Comment: Diz em qual linha está o erro agora

Comment: O erro ainda está dando o mesmo, porém depurando mostra na linha de        If arquivo = "" Or arquivo = "Falso" Then 'Se arquivo for igual a vazio, ou se ele clicar em cancelar retornar "falso", usuário não selecionou nenhum documento

Comment: Certo, fiz a modificação e tentarei outras para impedir o erro. Tudo bem, quando você puder estarei aqui esperando retorno! Muito obrigado.

Comment: E ao apagar essa linha depura na outra de Open arquivo For Input As #1, etc... É como você disse, ainda continuará dando erro porque teremos que testar o que está dentro da variavel do arquivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinto muito pela demora! Eis aqui:

```
Sub lerTxt()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim selecao As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, linha As Integer
    
    selecao = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt", Title:="Selecione um arquivo", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If VarType(selecao) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub 'Nenhum arquivo selecionado
    'Se não for boolean, é uma array de strings com caminhos de arquivo.
    
    ' Aqui é que você tem que iterar, pois "selecao" contém uma array com caminhos de arquivo.
    ' Dentro de cada iteração, você faz aquilo que você já estava fazendo.
    For i = 1 To UBound(selecao) Step 1
        Open selecao(i) For Input As #1
        Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        
        linha = 1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, valorLin
            Cells(linha, 1).Value = valorLin
            linha = linha + 1
        Loop
        Close #1
        
        sheet.UsedRange.TextToColumns Other:=True
        sheet.Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next i
End Sub
```